# line styles not applied in gnuplot (epslatex)

Tags: gnuplot

Hello i would like to draw 2 curves in a same plot using gnuplot (epslatex terminal). I am using a gnuplot script, which works just fine, except it doesn't apply line colors defined using command `set style line`.

Here is the script:

```
set terminal epslatex color colortext size 9cm,5cm
set size 1,1
set output "lorenzov_faktor.tex"

set xrange [0:10]
set yrange [0:10]

set xtics ("$0c$" 0, "$c$" 10)
set ytics ("$0$" 0, "$1$" 1, "$\\infty$" 10)

set style line 1 lc rgb "#FF0055"
set style line 2 lc rgb "#2C397D"

unset grid

set ylabel "$\\gamma$"
set xlabel "$u$"

set key left top

f(x) = 1/sqrt(1 - (x/10)**2) 
g(x) = 1

set xrange [0:11]
set yrange [0:9]

plot f(x) ls 2 lw 3 lt 1 title "$\\gamma$", g(x) ls 1 lw 1 lt 2 notitle
```

It produces a plot where colors dont match my definitions of line styles:
[image]

Comment: Change the terminal temporarily to e.g. `pdfcairo` and check if the problem persits. If it does, it's not TeX related and probably a wrong setting in your file.

Comment: Delte `lt 1` and `lt 2`; they are restoring the default line types in place of your user defined line styles.

Comment: @Ian Thompson if you add an anwser i will mark it as a solution. But can u tell me how, can i set dashed or dot-dashed line style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to delete `lt 1` and `lt 2` from your script, because they restore the default line types in place of your user defined line styles. Alternatively, you can change the line type (solid, dashed, etc.) without affecting the colour by using `lt` when you do `set style line`.

```
set style line 1 lc rgb "#FF0055" lt 1
set style line 2 lc rgb "#2C397D" lt 3

...

plot f(x) ls 2 lw 3 title "$\\gamma$", g(x) ls 1 lw 1 notitle
```